как получить значение checkbox при повторном открытии дочернего окна в tkinter?
Нужно открыть новое окно поставить галку , закрыть окно , потом заново открыть и что бы галка стояла.Не пойму почему метод .set() значение устанавливает но toplevel при повторном открытии его не видит
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
def click():# функция при нажатии на кнопку открывает новое окно и чекбокс
    def keep_checkbox(): # функция установки з-чия intvar
        if chk_var.get() == 0:
            pass
        else:
            chk_var.set(1)
        top_window.destroy()
    top_window = tk.Toplevel()
    chk_var = tk.IntVar()
    chk = ttk.Checkbutton(top_window, variable=chk_var).pack()
    top_window.protocol('WM_DELETE_WINDOW', keep_checkbox)
    top_window.mainloop()
root = tk.Tk()
frm = ttk.Frame(root).pack()
btn = ttk.Button(frm, text='Новое окно', command=click).pack()
root.mainloop()


так же если написать chk = ttk.Checkbutton(top_window, variable=chk_var.get()) задача решается но pycharm выдает предупреждение

решил задачу таким образом: сделал intvar переменную глобальной, и передал ее в качестве аргумента в функцию click() через лямбда-функцию:
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
def click(_intvar):# функция при нажатии на кнопку открывает новое окно и чекбокс
    top_window = tk.Toplevel()
    chk = ttk.Checkbutton(top_window, variable=_intvar).pack()
    top_window.mainloop()

root = tk.Tk()
chk_var = tk.IntVar()
frm = ttk.Frame(root).pack()
btn = ttk.Button(frm, text='Новое окно', command=lambda: click(chk_var)).pack()
root.mainloop()


.mainloop() нужно вызывать только у главного окна, дочерним окнам это не нужно

chk = ttk.Checkbutton(top_window, variable=_intvar).pack() - тут в chk запишется результат вызова метода pack(), который всегда None. Но тут в общем-то и не нужно сохранять Checkbutton в переменную.
